# React Navigation 4.x tabBarOptions not working Typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation

Please do not recommend me to use React Navigation 5.x, i use 4.x because of the switchNavigator, anyways. i'm having issues with the React Navigation 4.x after i migrated my project to typescript, this is part of the code that is getting an error.

```
 const MainTabs = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeStack,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => {
        const image = focused ? Images.inicio_onFocus : Images.inicio_onBlur;
        return <Image source={image} />;
      },
      tabBarOptions: {
        activeTintColor: colors.active,
        inactiveTintColor: colors.background,
        style: {
          marginTop: 10,
          height: 65,
          backgroundColor: colors.title,
          shadowColor: colors.inactive,
          borderTopColor: 'transparent',
          borderTopWidth: 0,
          elevation: 5,
          shadowOpacity: 5,
          shadowRadius: 10,
        },
      },
      tabBarLabel: 'INICIO',
    },
  },
  Vacations: {
    screen: VacationsStack,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => {
        const image = focused ? Images.vacaciones_onFocus : Images.vacaciones_onBlur;
        return <Image source={image} />;
      },
      /*
      tabBarOptions: {
        activeTintColor: colors.active,
        inactiveTintColor: colors.background,
        style: {
          marginTop: 10,
          height: 65,
          backgroundColor: colors.title,
          shadowColor: colors.inactive,
          borderTopColor: 'transparent',
          borderTopWidth: 0,
          elevation: 5,
          shadowOpacity: 5,
          shadowRadius: 10,
        },
      },
      */
      tabBarLabel: 'VACACIONES',
    },
  },
  HoursReport: {
    screen: HoursReportStack,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => {
        const image = focused ? Images.imputar_onFocus: Images.imputar_onBlur;
        return <Image source={image} />;
      },
      /*
      tabBarOptions: {
        activeTintColor: colors.active,
        inactiveTintColor: colors.background,
        style: {
          marginTop: 10,
          height: 65,
          backgroundColor: colors.title,
          shadowColor: colors.inactive,
          borderTopColor: 'transparent',
          borderTopWidth: 0,
          elevation: 5,
          shadowOpacity: 5,
          shadowRadius: 10,
        },
      },
      */
      tabBarLabel: 'IMPUTAR',
    },
  },
  ExpenseReport: {
    screen: ExpenseReportStack,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => {
        const image = focused ? Images.rendir_onFocus : Images.rendir_onBlur;
        return <Image source={image} />;
      },
      /*
      tabBarOptions: {
        activeTintColor: colors.active,
        inactiveTintColor: colors.background,
        style: {
          marginTop: 10,
          height: 65,
          backgroundColor: colors.title,
          shadowColor: colors.inactive,
          borderTopColor: 'transparent',
          borderTopWidth: 0,
          elevation: 5,
          shadowOpacity: 5,
          shadowRadius: 10,
        },
      },
      */
      tabBarLabel: 'RENDIR',
    },
  },
});
```

every part of the code that includes tabBarOptions is getting this error.

```
The expected type comes from property 'navigationOptions' which is declared here on type 'NavigationRouteConfig<NavigationBottomTabOptions, NavigationTabProp<NavigationRoute<NavigationParams>, any>, unknown>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the `tabBarOptions` is in the wrong place, maybe this way works for you:

`tabBarOptions` is not an attribute of `navigationOptions`. It should go inside the second parameter of `createBottomTabNavigator` just like `initialRouteName` for instance.

```
const MainTabs = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeStack,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => {
        const image = focused ? Images.inicio_onFocus : Images.inicio_onBlur;
        return <Image source={image} />;
      },
      tabBarLabel: 'INICIO',
    },
  },
  Vacations: {
    screen: VacationsStack,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => {
        const image = focused ? Images.vacaciones_onFocus : Images.vacaciones_onBlur;
        return <Image source={image} />;
      },
      tabBarLabel: 'VACACIONES',
    },
  },
  HoursReport: {
    screen: HoursReportStack,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => {
        const image = focused ? Images.imputar_onFocus: Images.imputar_onBlur;
        return <Image source={image} />;
      },
      tabBarLabel: 'IMPUTAR',
    },
  },
  ExpenseReport: {
    screen: ExpenseReportStack,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => {
        const image = focused ? Images.rendir_onFocus : Images.rendir_onBlur;
        return <Image source={image} />;
      },
      tabBarLabel: 'RENDIR',
    },
  },
}, {
  tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: colors.active,
    inactiveTintColor: colors.background,
    style: {
      marginTop: 10,
      height: 65,
      backgroundColor: colors.title,
      shadowColor: colors.inactive,
      borderTopColor: 'transparent',
      borderTopWidth: 0,
      elevation: 5,
      shadowOpacity: 5,
      shadowRadius: 10,
    }
  }
}});
```

Comment: well... that worked, quite strange since in my previous project (javascript), i had this the way i showed you, anyways, thanks a lot

Comment: Glad I could help! :) Yes, the library react-navigation is changing quite frequently the location of those attributes. Luckily I was able to find a personal project (which is running also on v4.x.x) and write down the solution for you.